# Retrieving Session attributes in Velocity Template set in Liferay Portlets

Tags: java, session, liferay, velocity

In my Portlet I set some attributes in the session which I wish to use in the velocity template that Liferay uses.

I set the attributes on `PortletSession` as follows:

```
portletSession.setAttribute("key", "value", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Now I wish to use these in my `home.vm` template of Liferay, but whatever I tried, nothing works:

```
$request.get("key") 
$request.getAttribute("key") 
$request.getSession().getAttribute("key")
$session.getAttribute("key")
```

I even put the key in the portal.properties:

```
session.shared.attributes=key
```

But that does not seem to work either. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself.

Apparantly I needed to set the `private-session-attributes` to false. I tried that before, but the DTD is very specific where it needs the tag.

After placing it at the right place, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to add the "LIFERAY_SHARED_" prefix to your session attribute name since the session.shared.attributes property's value contains it by default.